# symfony column not found error?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony1

I am trying to set up an existing symfony site from remote hosting on my local hosting and I am getting errors as :

```
[26-Mar-2017 12:35:48 Europe/Berlin]  [wrapped: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'video.COUPON_BANNER_ID' in 'field list']

[26-Mar-2017 12:35:49 Europe/Berlin] Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/favicon.ico" (/).

[26-Mar-2017 12:35:49 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PropelException' with message ' [wrapped: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'video.COUPON_BANNER_ID' in 'field list']' in D:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\lib\plugins\sfPropelPlugin\lib\vendor\propel\util\BasePeer.php:467
Stack trace:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\DrBerg.com\lib\model\om\BaseVideoPeer.php(392): BasePeer::doSelect(Object(Criteria), Object(PropelPDO))
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\DrBerg.com\lib\model\om\BaseVideoPeer.php(355): BaseVideoPeer::doSelectStmt(Object(Criteria), NULL)
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\DrBerg.com\lib\model\VideoCatPeer.php(24): BaseVideoPeer::doSelect(Object(Criteria))
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\DrBerg.com\apps\mainv2\modules\include\actions\components.class.php(61): VideoCatPeer::getNonEmptyVideoCategories()
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\lib\helper\PartialHelper.php(384): includeComponents->executeHeader(Object(sfWebRequest))
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\lib\helper\PartialHelper.php(148): _call_component('include', 'header', Array)
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\lib\helper\PartialHelper.p in D:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\lib\plugins\sfPropelPlugin\lib\vendor\propel\util\BasePeer.php on line 467
```

But as looking at the live site it seems that the field is not located in the DB video table but still the site works?

when I checked the file mentioned in the error so there was no mentioning of the field so then what's the case?

Comment: Can you show entities and related database tables?

Comment: Case sensivity?